# Git - How to print only the directories that were modified in earlier commit?

Tags: git, unix

I would like to know if there is any command which will print only the directory names in the current working directory that were modified(files were added, deleted or modified).

I tried using `git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD` but it prints the files that were changed. So, this would involve then `dirname` ing it to get the directory. Any other easy way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~10..HEAD -z | xargs -0 dirname | sort | uniq
```

The `-z` option asks for nul-separated output, which allows `xargs -0` to split on nul-characters in a robust way. `xargs dirname` applies the command `dirname` to each entry, and `sort | uniq` removes duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! I would have upvoted but i do not have reputation yet! :)

Comment: I will be deleting some content from the output of the above statement like for example :

`git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD -z | xargs -0 dirname | sort | uniq | sed '/something/d` 

but this something can get bigger as i write more codes. is there to way to pass a function to the pipe? Like for example `git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD -z | xargs -0 dirname | sort | uniq | delete_somethingS` where `delete_something` is a function which i declare beforehand with the sed delete statements.

Comment: This is becomming a different question (a shell question rather than a Git one). Essentially you want a for loop but open a different question if needed.